# deterministic annealing method

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have ran into a **shape matching problem** and one term which I read about is `deterministic annealing`. I want to use this method to convert discrete problems, e.g. travelling salesman problem to continuous problems which could assist of sticking in the *local minima*. I don't know whether there is already an implementation of this statistical method and also implementation of it seems a bit challenging for me because I couldn't completely understand what this method does and couldn't find enough documentations. Can somebody explain it more or introduce a library especially in `python` that got already implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You can see explication on [Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). Also, take a look to [scipy.optimize.anneal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.anneal.html).